# If $n\in \mathbb{N},$ then $(1-1/2) (1-1/4)(1-1/8)(1-1/16)...(1-1/2^n)\geq 1/4+1/2^{n+1}.$

Tags: inequality, induction, real-numbers

I would like to know how to prove the following statement:

If $n\in \mathbb{N},$ then 
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)...\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\geq  \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.$$

This is my attempt:
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)...\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\geq \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{.}{.}$$

Thanks

Masik

Comment: I assume that since you've tagged the question with the (induction) tag that you know that this question can be proven using mathematical induction. Have you attempted to prove it using induction? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: $$\left (1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\dots \left (1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\geq \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}$$

This is where I get struck.

Thank you.

Comment: Add it to the question.

Comment: My computation was wrong. I do not know how to go from there.

Comment: I understand that that is where you are getting stuck. I'm suggesting that you add that information to the question (by editing the question) so that it doesn't get closed for lack of context, and so that you don't have to add it as a comment to everyone's answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
How can you get from $$\left (1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\dots \left (1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$ to $$\left (1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\dots \left (1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$?

---

From the comment I see that you have thought about this, which is great, and you should include your thoughts in your question. That way it's less probable that your post will be closed. You have however made a small error. Notice that:

$$\left (\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}$$ so you only have to check that the inequality $$\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}\geq \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$$ holds. If you multiply boths sides by $2^{n+2}$ you get $$2-\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2}\geq 1$$

Comment: $$\left (1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left (1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\dots \left (1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\geq \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}$$

This is where I get struck.

Thank you.

Comment: @MasikKara Good, but you've made a small error. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)}=1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}.$$Since both expressions that you have are equal to $\frac12$ when $n=1$, all you need to prove is that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\geqslant\frac{\frac14-\frac1{2^{n+2}}}{\frac14-\frac1{2^{n+1}}}.$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Bernoulli's inequality*:
\begin{align}
\Bigl(1-\frac12\Bigr)\Bigl(1-\frac14\Bigr)\dots\Bigl(1-\frac1{2^n}\Bigr)&=\frac12\Bigl(1-\frac14\Bigr)\dots\Bigl(1-\frac1{2^n}\Bigr)\\
&\ge
\frac12\biggl[1- \Bigl(\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^n}\Bigr)\biggr]=\frac12\biggl[1- \frac14\Bigl(1+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-2}}\Bigr)\biggr]\\
&=\frac12\biggl[1-\frac12\Bigl(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\Bigr)\biggr]=\frac12\biggl(\frac12+\frac1{2^n}\biggr).
\end{align}